# Can I safely replace the speed of light by 0.5 in equations?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

In natural unit we set (for example in QCD) c->1, hbar->1, k->1.

All quantities can be expressed in terms of MeV. After the calculation, one can simply add c=3*10^8 properly.

However, if I want to set c->0.5 for numerical calculation, can I simply multiply $0.5*3*10^8$ after calculations? I did not find any reference for arbitrary values of basic constants.

Comment: Do you want to know the speed in meters per second at half lightspeed? In that case you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we "set" $c=1$ what we really mean is that we change from units of [ms$^{-1}$] (for example) to units of [$c=3\times10^{8}$ ms$^{-1}$]. So really, $c=1$ denotes that $c=1[c]$ where square brackets enclose the units. We are **not** choosing "arbitrary values for basic constants".

So, you are obviously allowed to work in whatever units you want: $c=1[c]=0.5[2c]=1/\pi[\pi c]=...$

> can I simply multiply $0.5∗3∗10^8$ after calculations

Not correct in general -- when your units are $[0.5c^{-1}]$, for example, you'd divide by the value instead.